# Why are rabbonim referred to by the names of their seforim?

Tags: names, rabbis, jewish-books

Many rabbonim who published important seforim are coloquially referred to by the names of one of the seforim. Why is this? When did it start?

Comment: A name makes the person ,and these gedolim are there seforim .

Comment: It makes sense: If someone wants to quote, say, the Tur - He's going to say "כתוב בטור". Compare the amount of times the Beis Yosef, the Bach, the Prisha/Drisha would refer to "the Tur says" over the amount of times one would refer to him as the person (as in R' Yaakov ben R' Asher was born in Germany)?

Comment: Note, some works were known by name rather than by "title" (such as "the Rambam" over "the Mishna Torah")

Comment: Note, btw, that we generally know someone by his most famous sefer (such that the Beis Yosef is known as "the Beis Yosef" not as "the Avkas Rochel" since "the Beis Yosef" appears more often in halacha than "the Avkas Rachel")

Comment: @Shmuel Youre mixing things up. כתוב בטור = it is written in _Tur_. Just like "It is written in _The Tempest_". It's not אמר הטור the _Tur_ said. That would be like "_The Tempest_ said in Act IV..." In old texts the author is usually written by name (רשב"א) by title (מרן) or in the context of his work (בעל העיטור), not by the title of his work itself. Using book titles that way is a much later development which is not grammatical and likely out of laziness or ignorance of the names of the authors. Can you tell me offhand the names of the authors of Taz, Shach, Bach, Magen Avraham and Sema'?

Comment: @doubleaa does the rashba have a title? Otoh, what about the behag?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin lol! Do you know what bahag stands for? (btw there are two Rashbas. R Shimshon ben Avraham and R Shlomo ben Aderet. The former is a Tosafist, the latter a student of R Moshe ben Nachman)

Comment: @DoubleAA Baal Halachos Gedolos. Not שמעון קיירא (I wikipedia's that)

Comment: @DoubleAA I assumed that "Baal" ... is still part of the question. Why do we know him as the "Baal Halachos Gedolos" and not R' Shimon Kayara

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Exactly. So we see even he wasn't referred to by the title of his book, הלכות גדולות, but as בעל הלכות גדולות == "the author of the book called הלכות גדולות" (btw there is much discussion about if R Shimon Kayara is actually the author of הלכות גדולות or not.)

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Only the OP can tell us that, but I don't think that is odd at all, eg. "The poem's author is trying to convey that..." Seems like a pretty normal way of speaking.