# Referring to a rav with multiple sefarim

Tags: jewish-books, rabbis

I've noticed that some rabbanim are referred to by the titles of multiple books. For example, R' Jair Bacharach (Wermeiser Rov between 1699-1702) is referred to both by the name of his shu"t, *Chavot Ya'ir*, and by the title of his commentary on Shulchan 'Aruch, *Mekor Chaim*.

What is the rationale for using different works to refer to one rav with?

Comment: See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/77793/mekor-chaim-by-the-chavauss-yoir

Comment: there's no official rule or rationale for these things, they just happen. It's like someone having multiple nicknames - it just happens because people start referring to him with those names. Many rabbanim aren't referred to by the titles of any of their books.

Comment: @Jay, true, but most of those who are only get referenced with one of their sefarim, such as the Chofetz Chaim (R' Yisrael Me'ir haKohen of Radun)

Comment: I've personally never heard him referred to as the "Mekor Chayim". I think most people don't even know he wrote a commentary on ShA. A better example might be R Joshua Falk who wrote Beit Yisrael and Meirat Einayim, and most everyone has heard of both those works but don't realize they have the same author (or that those are their proper names).

Comment: @WAF, I've never heard of the Chofetz Chaim being referred to as the Mishnah Berurah

Comment: @DoubleAA, I have, in multiple contexts.

Comment: @DoubleAA The question should apply at least as much to the _Noda Biy'huda_ / _Tzla"ch_ / _Dagul Mer'vava_ if you're looking for a good example.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt So that just shows that some people just like using certain names, and there is no rhyme or reason to be found in asking this.

Comment: @WAF Another good example, although there I think it's more commonly known that they have the same author.

Comment: @DoubleAA, in the case of the Chavot Ya'ir, it's more confusing, as there are multiple authors of sefarim of that name (see my linked question)

Comment: Possible duplicate  - depending on what the answer turns out to be: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27832/3

Comment: Is this on topic?

Comment: When a book is  celebrated it has its own existing. When someone wrote 2 known books it's as the father of Reuven and the father of Shim'on

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38470

Comment: הנודע ביהודע והצל"ח והדגול מרבבה,  השולחן ערוך והבית I am not convinced that the reference is always very clear יוסף.  הקצות,  הנתיבות והחוות דעת,  והאבמי מילואים